# Can I skip null values while using an iterator over an array list?

Tags: java, iterator

I am using an Iterator to iterate over an array list that contains many objects. At some point in my unit test I remove one of the objects and insert a null like so:

```
["123", "323", "433"]
```

to

```
["123", null, "433"]
```

How can I go about skipping over the null value with hasNext() and next() so the iterator can identify and ignore the null values while moving to the next non-null value in the list?
For example

```
["123", null, "433"]
```

returns

```
["123", "433"]
```

Here is what I have (although it probably has many issues).

Also, the get(int index) function returns the object at that location while the entryCount() returns the number of objects that exist in the list (including removed objects). If needed I can supply this function as well.

```
public class ArrayListIterator implements Iterator<Object> {
    
    int current = 0;
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        
        if(current < entryCount()) {
        
            return true;
    } 
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object next() {
        Object o = null;
           if (!hasNext()) {
               o = null;
                return o;
            } 
           
           else {
              try {
                o = get(current);   
                  } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                  } 
                }
                current+=1;
                return o;
           
                        }
    }
```

Comment: "*I'm sorry for the terrible formatting in advance.*" - ["*Do not be sorry. Be better.*" - Kratos (YouTube-link)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p0YNU1bSRoM)

Comment: well in the `next()` check if the object you have found is null or not, and do it until you does not have a next or the obj is not null

Answer (score 1):

You can `filter` out null values before iterating.

```
list.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).forEach(el -> {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: Yes, that is it.